# Erlang float_to_binary truncates decimals strangely

Tags: erlang, elixir

The Erlang `float_to_binary` function truncates decimals strangely. For instance, I would expect it to convert `0.45` with no decimal places to `"0"`. Instead we get (example in Elixir):

```
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(0.45, [decimals: 0])
"1"
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(0.445, [decimals: 0])
"1"
> :erlang.float_to_binary(0.444, [decimals: 0])
"0"
```

Thus, it seems like rounding is being applied iteratively from right to left until the desired number of decimals is reached.

Is this expected behavior? Why doesn't it either round correctly or just truncate? Both of those options seem much more predictable to me.

Comment: Which version of Elixir and Erlang are you on? I get `"0"` for `:erlang.float_to_binary(0.445, [decimals: 0])` with Elixir 1.6.6 and Erlang 21.

Comment: Elixir 1.5.2, Erlang 20

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a bug in Erlang which was [fixed on Jan 15 2018](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/c81c01da7b4870aa56cc38d865cd081f9bb800bc) and first included in Erlang 20.3. If you upgrade to Erlang 20.3 or later, you should get `"0"` for `0.445`.